# Declare or Instantiate many objects in one line

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Put it simply i want a way to make multiply class object in one line. like if it's in c++

```
class1 object1,object2,etc; //Make many object from class1

class1 object[x]; //and array of class
```

but how do you do it in as3? do i really have to write one by one like

```
var object1:class1=new class1;

var object2:class1=new class1;
```

Comment: For "array of class" take a look at `Vector` : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, when you instantiate a variable in AS3 using a complex data type you have to instantiate them separately if you wish for each variable to have a unique instance; however, you can declare your variables on one line.  So the following is ok, I just used MovieClip as an example:

```
var mc1:MovieClip, mc2:MovieClip, mc3:MovieClip;
mc1 = new MovieClip();
mc2 = new MovieClip();
mc3 = new MovieClip();
```

As Cherniv so nicely pointed out, you can instantiate multiple complex objects on one line; however if you do so, each variable that is instantiated on the that line, will have a reference to the *same* instance of that complex object. If that doesn't work for you, you have to do what I pointed out above.

```
var mc1:MovieClip, mc2:MovieClip, mc3:MovieClip;
mc1 = mc2 = mc3 = new MovieClip();
```

Comment: In case of "Primitive types" you can "instantiate" in one line , like `a = b = c = 5` ;)

Comment: +1 @Cherniv: Thanks for pointing that out, I simply didn't mention it since the poster was focusing on complex objects, but that is good information to know.  I will modify the verbiage to ensure it is more clear.

Comment: i think you need to point that there is no limitation to instantiate a complex types in one line too but in that case they all will reference to the same object

Comment: @Cherniv, edited my answer to include the details you further pointed out. Thanks again.